# Two names for the same github repo

Tags: github

Is it possible to create an alias or redirect to a GitHub repo?

For instance, is have the repo `org/my-repo`, and i want that when i clone the repo `org/my-repo-2` (that does not exist), the repo `org/my-repo` will actually be cloned.

I need it to support a CI/CD process for two separate services that use the same repo, but each one of should be deployed with a different configuration. I want the repo alias to prevent adding conditions to my code.

Comment: No, that is not possible. You should fix that in your CI/CD configuration. What are you using for that?

Comment: I'm using Jenkins and ArgoCD.

Comment: I’m not familiar with ArgoCD. Feels like you want to run your CI once and deliver an artifact, and then deploy it twice (with different configuration). Can’t you implement that?

Comment: First of all, i'll not have to deploy them twice each time. Each one of them suppose to run with a different version of the same service. I can implement it in my CI, but for that i would have to add some ugly conditions that i want to avoid. As part of the CI, i'm looking for the repo name, which so far was identical to the service name. Now i have a new use case: service name that is not identical to the repo name. If i was able to create an alias for the repo, i would not have to adjust my code.

Comment: So you do have two deploys with separate configuration. That is why I said, separate CI from CD. CI delivers the artifact, that can deployed (with any version) during the CD pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

If you rename a repository in github the old name continues to work on the same repository. The old name is like an alias to the new name.

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/renaming-a-repository

Comment: Yes. But the content of both repos will always be exactly the same and whenever you reference the old repo a warning will be logged that you're using the old name (in which place there is nothing stopping you from creating a new repo that would break the redirect).

Comment: @jessehouwing I think the original poster wanted the content of both repos to be exactly the same but referenced by different names. I haven't tried creating a new repo with the old name. It may not be possible, but, even if it is, we should choose not to do this. And if we accidentally break it, we could fix it with some more renaming.

Comment: Ohh yes, it works, but it would lead to some unexpected behavior.